# How to update nuget packages without package manager of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

How to update nuget packages without package manager of visual studio, if the projects referenced in solution have different nuget package folders, then updating nuget packages from solution becomes tedious job. You need to update nuget packages per project. Is there a way to update nuget packages without using visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the nuget packages in solution, you can create a batch file with multiple commands or can execute command like mentioned below using command prompt:

- Open command prompt and change the folder where Nuget.Exe is present.
- NuGet.Exe Update [Solution File] -Id [Nuget package Id]

There are more switches to Nuget.Exe Update switch,  like you can specify the nuget source. Make changes as required and you can successfully update nuget packages without opening the visual studio.