# Why does nuget update command line not update binding redirects in web / app.config?

Tags: c#, command-line, nuget

I am using the nuget command line tool to update my solution using the following tip found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662634/how-to-update-nuget-packages-without-package-manager-of-visual-studio)

But I discovered that it does not update binding redirects in web.config / app.config files.

How can I update the web.config / app.config files during an update on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

No, nuget.exe does not add or modify project contents during package update. You would need to use the PowerShell Console in Visual Studio or Visual Studio itself to do this. NuGet.exe does have an inherent knowledge of VS constructs like projects and only uses MSBuild to resolve P2P reference graphs.

Comment: Version 3.4.4 of nuget.exe is capable of updating packages.config and csproj files :)
It is just missing the update of binding redirects in config files, then everything can be scripted outside VS.